# Docker returning non-zero code even though ruby and bundler are updated

Tags: ruby, docker

I'm trying to dockerize my rail application using this command: 
`docker build -t nilocstore .` within my root rails app folder.

However, I continue to get this error when I do so:

> Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.13.7) is older than the
>   version that created the lockfile (1.16.6). We suggest you upgrade to
>   the latest version of Bundler by running 'gem install bundler'. Your
>   Ruby version is 2.3.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.5.1 The command
>   '/bin/sh -c bundle install' returned a non-zero code: 18

When I run `ruby -v` and `bundler -v` I get this:

> ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-darwin18]
>
> Bundler version 1.16.6

According to what that says, both my bundler and ruby are both updated, so why is it throwing me this error?

**Edit** - Here are the contents of my Dockerfile:

`FROM rails:onbuild`

Comment: Post your `Dockerfile` please.

Comment: Are you running `ruby -v` and `bundler -v` in the docker container or in your host machine.

Comment: @Iagom my dockerfile is as follows:

`FROM rails:onbuild

RUN bundler install`

Comment: @mcfinnigan I'm running it on the host machine. I tried adding `RUN bundler install` to my dockerfile so that it would update in the docker container but it still runs into the same issue.

Comment: Do you have a .ruby-version file locally? It would be helpful if you could post your Dockerfile and the various config files from your root directory.